# Is there any Stack Exchange site for discussing psychology?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am new to Stack Exchange. I know there is a lot of discussion sites for Stack Exchange.
I would like to know about there were any Stack Exchange site available for discussing and solving personal psychological problems.

Comment: Please do not use the internet as a resource in this type of matter.  It is in your best interest to find a local, licensed professional who can get to know your individual case and provide you with the care that you need.

Comment: Your search may have returned no results as the correct spelling is 'psychology'. Good luck.

Comment: At this stage we do not have a site for `discussing and solving personal psychological problems`  the cogsci site really is not suitable for this. I agree with @jonsca

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a beta site [Cognitive Sciences beta](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/) where you can ask questions related to Psychology. Before asking any question please have a look at it's [help page](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). But as [@jonsca](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200370/is-there-any-stack-exchange-site-for-discussing-psychology/200371#comment637663_200370) advised, please avoid too localized questions. If you have personal problem then it is not a site you are looking for.

From its help page:

> Cognitive Sciences Stack Exchange is for researchers, academics, students, and anyone else needing expert answers to advanced questions in the cognitive sciences.

Comment: Self-help questions are explicitly off-topic there

Comment: Key Point in the help page is that it's for "Researchers, Academics or Students" and not for solving personal problems.

Comment: @danielhanly.com - True enough updated.